# Program not running as expected

Tags: java

i wrote a  code of a game which gives you a word to unscrabble.But,not getting"You win", even after writing the correct word. All i get is" Wrong answer".Please find out the mistake and suggest ways to improve.

```
import java.util.*;
public class game {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand=new Random();

    //THE WORD DIRECTORY
    String[][] list=new String[][]{
            {"google","a search engine"},
            {"facebook","a social networking site"},
            {"java", "this language"},
      };

    //CHOOSING THRE WORD
    int n=rand.nextInt(3);
    String theword=list[n][0];
    String thehint=list[n][1];

    //JUMBLING THE WORD
    String jumbledword=theword;
    char a[] = jumbledword.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<jumbledword.length();i++){
        int input1=rand.nextInt(jumbledword.length());
        int input2=rand.nextInt(jumbledword.length());
        char temp=a[input1];
        a[input1]=a[input2];
        a[input2]=temp;

    }

    //THE GAME

        System.out.println("\t\tWELCOME TO JUMBLE WORD");
        System.out.println("1.Unscrabble the given word");
        System.out.println("2.Press 'hint'for hint");
        System.out.println("3.Press 'quit' to quit");
        System.out.print("The word:" );
        System.out.println(a);
     String guess;
    do{    guess=input.nextLine();

    if(guess==theword){
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    }
    else if(guess=="hint"){
        System.out.println(thehint);
    }
    else if(guess=="quit"){
        System.out.println("Better luck next time. The answer is :");
        System.out.println(theword);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Wrong answer .Try again");
    }




}while(!guess.equals("quit")&&!guess.equals(theword));

}}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `equals` method of the `String` class to compare the **contents** of two `String`s.

Using `==` on two class instances will just compare whether they are the **same** object.

For example:

```
if(guess.equals(theword))
```

Answer (score 2):

The == operator is used to check for object equality, not value. You want to use the equals method instead.

Instead of

```
if(guess==theword){
```

use

```
if(guess.equals(theword)){
```

Just to elaborate further, imagine you have three strings:

```
String s1 = new String("abc");
String s2 = s1;
String s3 = new String("abc");
```

In this case, the following results would occur:

```
s1.equals(s2); // true, same value
s1 == s2; // true, same object
s1.equals(s3); // true, same value
s1 == s3; // false, different objects
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals` instead of `==`.

Change if statement as, `if(guess.equals(theword)){`

**Explaination**:

In Java, when the “==” operator is used to compare 2 objects, it checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory. In other words, it checks to see if the 2 object names are basically references to the same memory location.

`equals` method can be overridden to **compare content** of the objects. As is done in String class.